# Ionic/Cordova menubutton event not called

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, android-menu

I am trying to monitor the Menu Button on Android (4.4.2 - Samsung S3), but the [Ionic event](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPlatform/) (nor the underlying [Cordova event](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/cordova_events_events.md.html#Events)) is not firing:

```
$ionicPlatform.on("menubutton", function () {
  // do our stuff here (never gets called)
});
```

Has anyone been able to make this work? Running Ionic platform 1.0.0, and all other events are firing as expected.

Comment: Could you provide some of your html code as well?

Comment: @QueryLars - there is not relevant HTML - on menubutton event, we'll execute some JS (indicated above with the comment block)

Comment: do you know for sure that this binding works ? can you post the block where you have this binding? Or can you put a log statement/alert to ensure your inline function is bound ?

Answer (score 3):

The docs are missing a line.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    ...
    navigator.app.overrideButton("menubutton", true);  // <-- Add this line
    document.addEventListener("menubutton", yourCallbackFunction, false);
    ...
}, false);
```

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9949#comment-14989073

Answer (score 2):

Try this: 
in the .run()

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
//...
     if (window.cordova) {
        $cordovaSplashscreen.hide();
        document.addEventListener("menubutton", myApp.onHardwareMenuKeyDown, false);
     }
/...
```

Then in the controller:

```
 $scope.onHardwareMenuKeyDown = function() {
    alert('menu button is working');
 }
```

Another way to do something:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCordova', 'ionic', 'myApp.controllers'])
  .run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $state, $localstorage,$ionicSideMenuDelegate ) {

     $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

      document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);

       function onMenuKeyDown() {
          console.log("some menu pops pup!! ");
          // here change the view , etc... 
          $rootScope.$apply();
        }

  });

})
```

Comment: Tried this code in my `.run()` code, but the function never gets triggered: `document.addEventListener("menubutton", function () { console.log("Menu Button); }, false);`