# Open sidemenu with Android hardware button in Ionic

Tags: android, menu, ionic-framework

i'm trying to open my sidemenu with android menu button. I found on internet this solution:

[Ionic/Cordova menubutton event not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790419/ionic-cordova-menubutton-event-not-called)

but it doesn't work for me. Here my code:

```
var starter = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])

    .run(function ($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $state, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
            // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
            // for form inputs)
            if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

            }
            if (window.StatusBar) {
                // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
                StatusBar.styleDefault();
            }

            document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);

            function onMenuKeyDown() {
                alert("some menu pops pup!! ");
                // here change the view , etc... 
                $rootScope.$apply();
            }


        });
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to overwrite the android methods!

This is my code:

```
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    navigator.app.overrideButton("menubutton", true);
    document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);

    function onMenuKeyDown() {
        console.log("Menu");
    }
});
```